# "react-native-lanscan" throws an exception ! undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.RNLAN_Scan.scan')?

Tags: javascript, react-native, node-modules, ping, icmp

To perform icmp broadcast in my react-native mobile app, I use react-native-lanscan package.

```
import { LANScan } from 'react-native-lanscan';
.
.
var lanscan = new LANScan();
.
.
pingBroadcaster = () => {
    console.log("Lanscan started!");         // to get log
    lanscan.scan(48500, 48503, 500, true);
    lanscan.on('host_found', (host, currentAvailableHosts) => {
        console.log(typeof(host));           // to get log
    })
    console.log("Lanscan ended!");           // to get log
}
```

When scan method is called in the arow function, it causes the exception: "undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.RNLAN_Scan.scan')"

Added some lines into **scan** method of the **lanscan** package to figure out which line causes error:

```
    function scan(min_port,max_port){
        console.log("   Function scan variable declaration");  // to get log
        var broadcast_timeout=arguments.length>2&&arguments[2]!==undefined?arguments[2]:500;
        var fallback=arguments.length>3&&arguments[3]!==undefined?arguments[3]:true;
        var ping_ms=arguments.length>4&&arguments[4]!==undefined?arguments[4]:50;
        var port_ms=arguments.length>5&&arguments[5]!==undefined?arguments[5]:500;
        console.log("   Function call: " + RNLAN_Scan);        // to get log
        this.RNLAN_Scan.scan(min_port,max_port,broadcast_timeout,fallback,ping_ms,port_ms);
        console.log("   Function scan Ends!");                 // to get log        
    }return scan;}()},
```

I've received these logs:

```
Lanscan started!
   Function scan variable declaration
   Function call: null
::ffff:192.168.43.1 - - [26/Feb/2020:14:23:16 +0000] "POST /symbolicate HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"
Lanscan started!
   Function scan variable declaration
   Function call: null
::ffff:192.168.43.1 - - [26/Feb/2020:14:23:21 +0000] "POST /symbolicate HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"
Lanscan started!
   Function scan variable declaration
   Function call: null
::ffff:192.168.43.1 - - [26/Feb/2020:14:23:26 +0000] "POST /symbolicate HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"
Lanscan started!
```

Seems like  **RNLAN_Scan** returns **null** 
I'm not sure, but maybe something is going wrong with this line :

```
var RNLAN_Scan=_reactNative.NativeModules.RNLANScan;
```